# Altium: Design rule to highlight a plane that is not assigned to a net

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, drc, design-rules

In Altium Designer 20.1.14.287 I tried to create a design rule that would highlight that a plane is not assigned to any net after running the DRC. But in the PCB Rules and Constraints Editor I only find rules for plane clearance and connect style.

How can I create such a rule? Maybe with a query?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on one of the many Altium support groups before asking here?